# Utilizar exemple do JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Preciso fazer uma busca no banco onde possuo um objeto que está com tudo preenchido menos o id e verificar se possui algum objeto que da um "Match" com ele e retorná-lo! Pensei em fazer um @Query e verificar se todos são iguais, só que meu chefe disse que este não e o padrão e possui um Exemple do JPA Repository que só encontrei ele desta forma aqui:

```
public interface LeagueRepository extends JpaRepository<League, Long>{

League findByName(String name);

boolean existsByTeams(Team team); }
```

Onde você passa um objeto que está dentro da sua entidade e ele verifica se tem em tau coluna este objeto. Porem ele não verifica na entidade que ele está.

Por exemple algo do tipo: "obs este código abaixo não funciona"

```
public interface LeagueRepository extends JpaRepository<League, Long>{

League findByName(String name);

boolean exists(League league); }
```

Onde o objeto Legue possui tudo menos o id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço alguma função que faça isso no jpa, mas se vc fazer dessa forma aqui:

```
Collection<League> findByNameAndOtherField (String name, String otherField);
```

acredito que encontre todas as linhas antes de realizar sua operação.

Obs: as vezes o nome do método fica gigante e compensa realmente usar o `@query`

Comment: A solução atende muito obrigado.